Does order in WHERE clause in Trino SQL matter?
How does Trino engine resolve order in WHERE  clause?
For example we have query 1:
select *
from some_schema.some_table
where partition_column = 'yyyy-MM-dd' -- this is some date, the table partition
  and non_partition_column = 'some-value' -- not partition column

And we have same query but with different order in WHERE clause, as query 2:
select *
from some_schema.some_table
where non_partition_column = 'some-value' -- not partition column
  and partition_column = 'yyyy-MM-dd' -- this is some date, the table partition

Which query will be execute faster? Or it doesn't matter?

@Justinas Why would there be any order in the output sans any ORDER BY clause?

Generally, we don't control which of the two WHERE conditions gets evaluated in which order...but the optimizer might decide this order.

Run EXPLAIN SELECT * ... yourself and look at the differences, if any. https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/explain.html

@BeRT2me there are no differences, thx!

There is no difference. The query engine will compile your query into the most efficient sequence of operations it can figure out that would result in the correct results.
Since the boolean expressions a AND b and b AND a are equivalent, the engine can run things in any way it wants, as long as the result is functionally equivalent to an AND of the two predicates.
In your particular example, Trino will see that one of the predicates is a partition predicate. The engine wants to run these early, to reduce as much data as possible as early as possible. It can do this because filtering first by the partition predicate and then by the non-partition predicate will result in the exact same result as filtering by the non-partition predicate and then the partition predicate – the latter would just be a lot less efficient.
